# connect ETIMEDOUT Node.js

Tags: node.js, auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

I am using a `create hook` in my [Auth0 Delegated Administration Extension](https://github.com/auth0-extensions/auth0-delegated-administration-extension).

I am getting this error when trigger the create hook:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
```

Create Hook function is:

```
function(ctx, callback) {

    var request = require('request');

    // Perform any asynchronous actions
    var API_URL = "https://example.com:8081/api/saveData";

    var empFirstName = 'Jhone';
    var empId = '123';

    request.post({
            url: API_URL,
            json: {
                firstName: empFirstName,
                userId: empId
            }
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                ctx.log('Create failed to '+API_URL+':', error);
                return callback(new Error('Something went wrong. Please try again.'));
            }
            ctx.log('Create successful!  Server responded with:', body);
            return callback(null, {
                /*some data here*/
            });
        });
}
```

I have tried with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and it works as expected. But with the create hook, I am getting above error.

What could be the issue?

Comment: what does your callback look like?

Comment: Try using postman and see if it is responding?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa This does not even hit the server. I have added console log in endpoint and it is never printed.

Comment: @NidhinDavid Yeah. I tried with postman and It's worked.

Comment: Just to confirm, so the actual failing call is the one to "https://example.com:8081/api/saveData", and a call to this same endpoint works fine in postman ?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa Yeah. call to same endpoint works fine with postman

Comment: https://example.com:8081/api/saveData does return a timeout no matter where I use it. Is this the actual endpoint you are hitting or are u using it as a placeholder for the sake of this question?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa example.com is not the actual domain. it is only for example purpose. I can't expose the actual URL here.

Comment: Do you get some sort of response if you hit any other url? such as https://httpbin.org/post

Comment: I have the same issue. I still can't figure out how to solve it, but I think it has to do with proxy

Comment: Met the same issue, I'm using azure cosmos DB api. Postman can finish the call, however, nodejs / python / C# cannot finish the call. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your endpoint is unavailable or not responding.

Are you sure this endpoint handle content-type: application/json ? otherwise try to send it as x-form-www-urlencoded.

```
request.post({
    url: MY_URL,
    form: {
        firstName: empFirstName,
        userId: empId
    }
```

Comment: No luck with this too